# Using Queue in Azure Storage

Tags: .net, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-queues, azure-webjobs-triggered

I am try to solve 1 problem with using AzureStorage.Queue in .NET.

First, I have 2 project, 1 project Web API, 1 project for WebJob. (All write in .NET Core 2.2)

- My project API when Create new product, It will insert 1 message store Id of product to Message Queue in Azure (Queue name : product)
- At same time in my project Web Job, I have 1 function using [QueueTrigger["product"]] to listen when new message inserted in my "product" queue. But I dont know why after message inserted to "product" queue, my message automatic deleted and inserted into another queue name "product-poison" ?
- I am using same connection string to Azure Storage in 2 Project. I Have try to use different connection string but result is the same.

Thanks for supporting me.

Comment: Read here about error handling and poison queues https://blog.tech-fellow.net/2019/02/06/capture-exception-in-azure-functions-poison-queue-trigger/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your queue trigger function consumed the message generate by your API project, and it seems the function did not consume it with a correct format.

Here is an article tells why poison-queue has been generate: [Poison messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=csharp#poison-messages)

> When a queue trigger function fails, Azure Functions retries the
> function up to five times for a given queue message, including the
> first try. If all five attempts fail, the functions runtime adds a
> message to a queue named -poison.